# How to use Google MapView in android apllication?

Tags: android

I am trying to use MapView provided by Google API. I am not able to import the package i saw in google page we need to get a key for using google API do anyone know how to use Google API.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [blog entry](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android). There it is explained how to setup and use the map API of Google. The API key is free.